# Whats wrong with my LinkedList remove method

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

What's wrong with my remove function,
I can remove head but cannot remove any other node.

```js
SLinkedList.prototype.remove = function(value) {
  if(!this.findValue(value) )return;
  if(this.head.value === value){
    this.head = this.head.next;
    return;
  }
  var prev = null;
  var cur = this.head;
  while(cur.value !== value){
    prev = cur;
    cur = cur.next
  }
  prev.next = cur.next;
}
```

This is a link to full javascript implementation
[repl it](https://repl.it/Flg7/0)

Comment: The code above appears to correspond to `SLinkedList.prototype.findValue` and not `SLinkedList.prototype.remove`

Comment: That function is checking if that value exist that linked list. You cal click on "repl it" link to see the full implementation

Comment: well... your remove method (per code) removes only head value or head.next value (if you fix the condition to check for this.head.next.value === value). But it does not go any further. So perhaps you want to first iterate over the list and find element, where next.value is value.

Comment: thanks just realized that I entered wrong snipped, just changed it

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your fineValue() method.  First your while loop was looking at this.head which was never changing.  Second you were returning false after the first iteration.  Hope this helps.

```
SLinkedList.prototype.findValue = function(value) {
 if (!this.head) return false
  var cur = this.head;
  while (cur) { //Need to check cur not this.head
   if (cur.value === value) {
    return true
   }
   cur = cur.next
   //return false; //Move this out of the while loop
 }
 return false
}
```